# How do I track down Kant reference AK 3:556

Tags: kant, critique-of-pure-reason

Trying to figure out how to understand references to the works of Kant.  The context is from a translator introduction of *Critique of Practical Reason* that is referring to the *Critique of Pure Reason*.

> In November 1786 the *Allgemeine Literaturzeitung*, announcing the
> forthcoming publication of the new edition, said that in it a critique of pure practical reason would be appended to the critique of pure speculative reason contained in the first edition (AK 3:556).

I'm assuming the three refers to volume three of the Academy Edition, which I think is the first edition of the *Critique of Pure Reason*, but if I go to the online website, the German pages end at page 553.  I'm guessing these are comments, annotations, reviews, etc., that were printed at the end of the first edition? And these aren't usually included with translations such as the Cambridge translation?

Comment: The original announcement is "Kurze Nachrichten" https://zs.thulb.uni-jena.de/rsc/viewer/jportal_derivate_00097644/ALZ_1786_Bd3u4_515.tif

Comment: Thank you for this.  I've been looking for it in the online Duibsurg Bände without success.

Answer (score 3):

It refers to the British Academy Edition of Kant's writings, by volume:page number. So this would mean it's referencing the third volume, page 556. This is the Critique of Pure Reason B edition in the collection. According to [this website](https://users.manchester.edu/facstaff/ssnaragon/kant/Helps/AcadEd.htm#Werke) that volume has 594 pages.

I found a copy online, the page that is being referenced is from Benno Erdmann's introduction to the volume, in the *Anmerkungen* section. As you said, because it's an introduction and not written by Kant it isn't included in the translation.

I can't read German so I could be wrong, but from what I can see it seems it's the right place, as it discusses the same things your quoted passage does, for example (a google translate of an excerpt from the page):

> [Kant] will also add to the criticism of pure speculative reason contained in the first edition, a criticism of pure practical reason in the second edition

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 I added a link to the original announcement. You are right.

Answer (score 2):

For Kant's writings, the definitive edition has been accepted as the one published by Königlich-Preußische Akademie der Wissenschaften (the Royal Prussian Academy of Sciences; later replaced by Berlin-Brandenburgische Akademie der Wissenschaften).

Citation to that original German editioned has the format

{Ak} {volume number in the series}: {page number}

Hence, AK 3:556 refers to the 3rd volume in the series, 2nd or B-edition of *Critique of Pure Reason* (Kritik der reinen Vernunft) which ends on page 552.

The mentioned note is in the Notes (Anmerkungen) section and as follows:

[image]

Comment: For a link to the original text see the comment to the OP's question.